# Cutting out scraped dates and grouping by day?

Tags: php, loops, simple-html-dom

I use the following to scrape soccer fixtures from a site...

```
// Retrieve the URL
$url = 'http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/fixtures/';
$html = @file_get_html($url);

//cuts out just the table
$FullFixTable = $html->find('table[class=ismFixtureTable]',0);

// Find all results and break them up into pieces
foreach($FullFixTable->find('tr[class=ismFixture]') as $ResultsToCutOut) 
{
    $GameDate = $ResultsToCutOut->find('td',0)->innertext;
      $Date = substr($GameDate, 0, 6);
      $Time = substr(substr($GameDate, 0, -4), (strlen(substr($GameDate, 0, -6))-5)*-1);
    $HomeTeam = $ResultsToCutOut->find('td',1)->innertext;
    $AwayTeam = $ResultsToCutOut->find('td',5)->innertext;

    echo $Date.' '.$Time.' '.$HomeTeam.' v '.$AwayTeam.'<br>';
}
```

This echoes....

```
May 15 7:30PM Philadelphia Union v Los Angeles Galaxy
May 18 5:00PM Toronto FC v Columbus Crew
May 18 7:00PM Vancouver Whitecaps v Portland Timbers
May 18 7:30PM Philadelphia Union v Chicago Fire
May 18 8:30PM Houston Dynamo v New England Revolution
May 18 10:30PM San Jose Earthquakes v Colorado Rapids
May 18 10:30PM Seattle Sounders FC v FC Dallas
May 19 1:00PM New York Red Bulls v Los Angeles Galaxy
May 19 5:00PM D.C. United v Sporting Kansas City
May 19 10:30PM Chivas USA v Real Salt Lake
```

Which is fine... but I want the information in this order....

```
May 15
  7:30PM Philadelphia Union v Los Angeles Galaxy
May 18
  5:00PM Toronto FC v Columbus Crew
  7:00PM Vancouver Whitecaps v Portland Timbers
  7:30PM Philadelphia Union v Chicago Fire
  8:30PM Houston Dynamo v New England Revolution
  10:30PM San Jose Earthquakes v Colorado Rapids
  10:30PM Seattle Sounders FC v FC Dallas
May 19
  1:00PM New York Red Bulls v Los Angeles Galaxy
  5:00PM D.C. United v Sporting Kansas City
  10:30PM Chivas USA v Real Salt Lake
```

Any idea how I would do that? I know I can use `substr` to cut stuff out, but I have no idea how to group it by similar date. Dates will always be `M d g:iA T` format, so there's probably a far easier and better way to cut out than the way I used above.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If the results are already ordered, only echo `$Date` if you didn't already echo that `$Date` (so store echoed dates somewhere). If the results aren't ordered, build an array like `$results[$Date][] = $restofyourstring`, and loop through those at the end.

Comment: @Wrikken The results are ordered by date chronologically, but I don't know how to get my code to know if multiple dates are the same, then group them together. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if ( !isset($lastDate) || $Date !== $lastDate ) {
    echo $Date.'<br>';
    echo $Time.' - '.$HomeTeam.' v '.$AwayTeam.'<br>';
    $lastDate = $Date;
} else {
    echo $Time.' - '.$HomeTeam.' v '.$AwayTeam.'<br>';
}
```